# Why is my function returning wrong values?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [question about leading zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232534/question-about-leading-zeros)

As in [stackoverflow.com/questions/3232534/question-about-leading-zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232534/question-about-leading-zeros).

Number of trailing zeros, binary search from Hacker's Delight:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int ntz(unsigned   x){

 int n;

 if ( x==0) return 32;
 n=1;
 if ((x & 0x0000FFFF))==0) {n=n+16; x=x>>16;}
 if ((x & 0x000000ff)==0) {n=n+8;x>>=8;}
 if ( x &0x0000000F)==0) {n=n+4; x>>=4;}
 if ((x & 0x00000003)==0) { n=n+2; x>>=2;}
   return n-(x &1);
}

int main(){

 unsigned   x;
 cin>>x;
 cout<<ntz(x)<<endl;

  return 0;
}
```

When i enter 8 it return 8  and when I enter 9 the same result why?

Comment: Can't explain it - the code you posted has syntax errors (you should use copy-n-paste when posting), which when fixed in a straightforward manner give the expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, your code doesn't compile.  The parentheses in lines 9 and 11 are not balanced correctly.

That said, after fixing the errors and compiling, I get the following results:

```
$ ./a.out 
8
3

$ ./a.out 
9
0
```

Comment: yes danben i have tested problem was that i have not created new project just  delete code in  the same project and write another code into it so it  repeated result from old code

Comment: All that means is that you didn't build the project after changing the code (assuming i'm understanding correctly).